# Acknowledge purchase returns developer error "5" android studio

Tags: java, android, billing

I am using the standard flow provided by the google developer guides, as referred to here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate?hl=es-419#process

I tried to get just a tiny bit deeper than it states in the acknowledge logic, waiting for the acknowledgement to be completed and successfull by using this code:

```
AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken()).build();
    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(
                    acknowledgePurchaseParams,
                    new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Consumed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    );
```

I tried to run it but it doesn't work. Finally, by debugging, I found out that responseCode is returning a 5, which means "DEVELOPER ERROR", instead of a 0 ("OK").

Any ideas??

Comment: Are you doing the acknowledgement inside `onBillingSetupFinished` of  `billingClient.startConnection` ?

Comment: I am calling it in `onBillingSetupFinished`, which is inside `billingClient.startConnection` @TorkelVelure

Comment: Great question. Have the same issue. Although, with the same code, half the time I get error 5, the other half is a success. Where's the developer error in that?